# ios application crashes with an incomprehensible error

Tags: ios, swift, crash

Good afternoon.
I have received app crash reports from users. In the Reports->Crashes (Xcode -> Organaizer) I found the messages (logs) I needed. Previously, when clicking on "open in project", Xcode opened the debugger at the crash site with a message (if it was due to nil or something). But now it only shows the error stack and that's it. The required class does not open, not to mention the place of the crash.

I suspect that the crash is related to some ui events. But I don't know how to decipher them in detail. Previously, I did not work with crashes in more detail and I do not know how to thoroughly analyze them.

Could you recommend any tutorial or articles? Could you suggest what might be causing the error. There were several crashes of the series until the user deleted the application. I am attaching the logs of the very first crash in this queue.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ed766090 objc_opt_class + 36 (objc-object.h:237) 

1   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d70b37ac -[UIWindow _windowInterfaceOrientation] + 24 (UIWindow.m:4960)

2   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d7238030 -[UIWindow _sceneSafeAreaInsetsIncludingStatusBar:] + 52 (UIWindow.m:2591)

3   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d70adfec -[UIScrollView _baseInsetsForAccessoryOnEdge:hasCustomClientInsets:accessorySize:additionalInsetFromEdge:] + 212 (UIScrollView.m:12675)

4   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d739243c -[UIScrollView _effectiveHorizontalScrollIndicatorInsets] + 200 (UIScrollView.m:12795)

5   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d7287b9c -[UIScrollView _layoutHorizontalScrollIndicatorWithBounds:effectiveInset:contentOffset:fraction:additionalInset:cornerAdjust:showing:recalcSize:verticalIndicatorFrame:] + 384 (UIScrollView.m:9506)

6   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d72035c8 -[UIScrollView _adjustScrollerIndicators:alwaysShowingThem:] + 1296 (UIScrollView.m:9386)

7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d72c1ddc -[UIScrollView _updateForChangedScrollIndicatorRelatedInsets] + 140 (UIScrollView.m:3606)

8   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d7153784 _UIScrollViewAdjustForOverlayInsetsChangeIfNecessary + 592 (UIScrollView.m:12877)

9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d816293c -[UIScrollView _updateForChangedEdgesConvertingSafeAreaToContentInsetWithOldSystemContentInset:oldEdgesPropagatingSafeAreaInsets:adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary:] + 116 (UIScrollView.m:2467)

10  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d709cd9c -[UIScrollView setContentSize:] + 1816 (UIScrollView.m:2421)

11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d70596d4 -[UIScrollView _applyConstrainedContentSizeIfNecessary] + 112 (UIScrollView.m:1443)

12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d708362c -[UIScrollView layoutSubviews] + 60 (UIScrollView.m:1476)

13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d7074844 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2592 (UIView.m:18426)

14  QuartzCore                      0x00000001d87ea1c0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 532 (CALayer.mm:10116)

15  QuartzCore                      0x00000001d87dc5fc CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 136 (CALayer.mm:2479)

16  QuartzCore                      0x00000001d87f0f70 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 452 (CAContextInternal.mm:2612)

17  QuartzCore                      0x00000001d87f9e78 CA::Transaction::commit() + 704 (CATransactionInternal.mm:449)

18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d70836d8 _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 84 (UIApplication.m:2977)

19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d7053a38 __processEventQueue + 7412 (UIEventDispatcher.m:2639)

20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d7058c9c __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 172 (UIEventDispatcher.m:2668)

21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d4b33f04 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1972)

22  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d4b44c90 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208 (CFRunLoop.c:2016)

23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d4a7e184 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268 (CFRunLoop.c:2053)

24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d4a83b4c __CFRunLoopRun + 828 (CFRunLoop.c:2951)

25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d4a976b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)

26  GraphicsServices                0x00000001f0b31374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)

27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d73fce88 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511)

28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d717e5ec UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064)

29  APPNAME                         0x0000000100cafc60 main + 68 (UIView.swift:13)

30  dyld                            0x00000001012f9ce4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)
 

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000016030a130   x1: 0x000000021f701692   x2: 0x00000001012e1940   x3: 0x000000010133a328
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000f20
    x8: 0x010000022db9944f   x9: 0x000000021f701692  x10: 0x000000016cca86da  x11: 0x01ff00015e030400
   x12: 0x00000000000000bf  x13: 0x000000015e030fd0  x14: 0x0000000000000018  x15: 0x000000022db99448
   x16: 0x000000022db99448  x17: 0x000000022db99448  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016030a130
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x0000000000000004  x22: 0x000000021e8f47df  x23: 0x00000002838a6e00
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000000000005d0  x26: 0x000000022db84840  x27: 0x0000000000000460
   x28: 0x0000000000000068   fp: 0x000000016f153130   lr: 0x00000001d70b37ac
    sp: 0x000000016f153120   pc: 0x00000001ed766090 cpsr: 0x60000000
   esr: 0x92000047 (Data Abort) byte write Translation fault


Binary Images:
0x100ca8000 - 0x100e7ffff APPNAME arm64  <9132dc7750703059bb23bb964dc7c319> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/438CAE39-5E52-4E70-A046-55DC0EE12F36/APPNAME.app/APPNAME
0x1012e0000 - 0x101337fff dyld arm64e  <d16b72c0d6193e4892622c10a1d3066f> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1d4a78000 - 0x1d4ecdfff CoreFoundation arm64e  <d2716f2f688b3d51ba8b17e6553b209e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1d5296000 - 0x1d5756fff CFNetwork arm64e  <eae64611a84036fea69d5658f1bcf4d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1d6266000 - 0x1d656efff Foundation arm64e  <feeef9b1b0e63561adfa3ef0302d23f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1d6ee9000 - 0x1d8783fff UIKitCore arm64e  <e6e89bb5b5863725bf8f4c85dcd443bd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1d87aa000 - 0x1d8ab9fff QuartzCore arm64e  <a491ae8b354b35c1ab22af42a96b6704> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x1de07a000 - 0x1de0a4fff AudioSession arm64e  <37d438b9289d39b08b671b38de65305f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AudioSession.framework/AudioSession
0x1e405f000 - 0x1e675bfff WebCore arm64e  <49f330352d3a3aa5bf5a4f25ca8b8c77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x1ed760000 - 0x1ed79cfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <a196a0f6cadb325bbc1f5965e670f9b6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1f0b30000 - 0x1f0b38fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <75a910dc87a43b3a8c0ea868b945f5d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x20c479000 - 0x20c4aefff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <c2fcc05874803c14b4790064a3f843e3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x245a95000 - 0x245aa0fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <b48efcbed4f7308ba3fa172e0ea78e33> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the issue is because of change in content size of UIScrollView on changing the device orientation.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/2805-demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs

This tutorial on understanding crash logs might be helpful to you.

Thank you